# Convert templated type into ID

Tags: c++

I have a project where I need to have the ability to convert a given type into an ID.

This code doesn't compile, but I hope it shows the functionality I am trying to achieve.

```
class TypeIDManager {
public:
    template <typename Type>
    void setTypeID(std::size_t ID) {
        m_data.insert({ typeid(Type), ID });
    }

    template <typename Type>
    std::size_t getTypeID() {
        return m_data[typeid(Type)];
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_info, std::size_t> m_data;
};
```

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) is meant for:

```
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::size_t> m_data;
```

`std::type_info` is implicitly convertible to `std::type_index` via its converting constructor, so you don't need to change the way you insert into the map.

However `std::type_index` doesn't have a default constructor which is required for `std::unordered_map`'s `operator[]`.

So you will need to use the [`find`/`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) methods instead to retrieve values, e.g.

```
return m_data.at(typeid(Type));
```

which will throw an exception if the key isn't found.